# Output custom post shortcode. Help spot the error.

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

so I have written the below shortcode that outputs a list of custom posts. When I echo out the values it works fine. But when I do it a slightly different way and join variables it does not. It doesn't really matter but I would like to now why.

This works fine.

```
function post_events($atts) {

  global $post;

  $args = array(
      'post_type'    => 'event',
      'post_status'  => 'publish',
      'orderby'      => 'date',
      'order'        => 'ASC',
  );

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  $posts_chunks = array_chunk($posts, 2);

  foreach ($posts_chunks as $row) {

    echo '<div class="row">';

      foreach ($row as $post) {

        setup_postdata($post);

        echo '<div class="col-md-6 event-item">';
        echo '<a href="' .get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_post_thumbnail(). '</a>';
        echo '<div class="event-item-text">';
        echo '<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';
        echo '<span class="event-date">' .get_the_date("Y-m-d"). '</span>';
        echo '<p>' .wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ). '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

      }

    echo '</div>';

      }

}

add_shortcode('post_events','post_events');
```

For some reason this only outputs the first post...

```
function post_events($atts) {

  global $post;

  $args = array(
      'post_type'    => 'event',
      'post_status'  => 'publish',
      'orderby'      => 'date',
      'order'        => 'ASC',
  );

  $posts = get_posts($args);

  $posts_chunks = array_chunk($posts, 2);

  foreach ($posts_chunks as $row) {

    echo '<div class="row">';

      foreach ($row as $post) {

        setup_postdata($post);

        $output = '<div class="col-md-6 event-item">';
        $output .= '<a href="' .get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_post_thumbnail(). '</a>';
        $output .= '<div class="event-item-text">';
        $output .= '<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';
        $output .= '<span class="event-date">' .get_the_date("Y-m-d"). '</span>';
        $output .= '<p>' .wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ). '</p>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';

        return $output;

      }

    echo '</div>';

      }

}

add_shortcode('post_events','post_events');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're resetting the value of `$output` each time you go through the loop:

```
foreach ($row as $post) {
        // etc.

        $output = '<div class="col-md-6 event-item">'; // Here $output 

        // etc.
}
```

That `$output` assignment is resetting the value of `$output` to `'<div class="col-md-6 event-item">'`, throwing out everything that had been appended to it.

You're also returning `$output` at the end of the first loop:

```
foreach ($row as $post) {
    // etc.

    return $output;

}
```

That stops the entire function and returns the current value of `$output`, which will only be the first post at that point.

You'll need to declare `$output` outside the loops (both of them), then only append from that point on, and return after the loops have finished:

```
function post_events($atts) {
    global $post;

    $args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'event',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'orderby'      => 'date',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    $posts_chunks = array_chunk($posts, 2);

    $output = '';

    foreach ($posts_chunks as $row) {

        $output .= '<div class="row">';

        foreach ($row as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);

            $output .= '<div class="col-md-6 event-item">';
            $output .= '<a href="' .get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_post_thumbnail(). '</a>';
            $output .= '<div class="event-item-text">';
            $output .= '<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';
            $output .= '<span class="event-date">' .get_the_date("Y-m-d"). '</span>';
            $output .= '<p>' .wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ). '</p>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('post_events','post_events');
```